# getting error Unsupported major.minor version 49.0 while doing maven build

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build my project but everytime getting error 
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean': Unable to find the mojo 'org.apach
e.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin'
org/apache/maven/plugin/clean/CleanMojo (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)

I am using java 1.4.2_16 and maven 2.0.6

I tried to build it using java 1.5 and build is successfull.
But the problem is my application should be built in java 1.4 only.
I dont know why it is giving error for 1.4. All classes are compiled in java 1.4 only.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a Maven plug-in which requires at least Java 5.

Comment: for Maven 2.0.6 java 1.4 is ok. I verified it with maven docs

Comment: Yes, but you are using a **plug-in** which requires at least Java 5.